# Inequality on monotone function integration

Tags: measure-theory, integration

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative monotone function defined on the $[0,1]$. Prove that $$\mu_L(\{w\in I;f(w)>\alpha\})<\dfrac1\alpha\int_0^1fdx$$ where the measure is the Lebesgue measure, and the integral is the Riemann integral.

So let $f$ be monotone increasing (monotone decreasing should be similar). Suppose $f(w)=\alpha$ at $w=r$. So $\mu_L(\{w\in I;f(w)>\alpha\}) = 1-r$. Then partitioning $[0,1]$ into $[0,r],[r,1]$, we have $\int_0^1fdx$ is at least $\alpha(1-r)$. But still, it might be equal to $\alpha(1-r)$. How can we eliminate that possibility?

Comment: $\int_0^1fdx>\int_r^1fdx\ge\alpha(1-r)$

Comment: @Pocholapantera That's not true. It is possible that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,r)$.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I was thinking in a positive function. Well, then the proposition is false, unless some aditional hypothesis is added.

Comment: @Pocholapantera Can you give a counterexample where it's false?

Comment: It is not my day. Now I was thinking in condition $f(w)\ge \alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continue your reasoning.

Let $f$ be monotone increasing. Define $r=\sup \{w\,;\,f(w)\le \alpha\}$. Then

$\mu_L(\{w\in I;\,f(w)>\alpha\})=1−r$

For the other side,

$$
\int_0^1f\,dx\ge \int_r^1f\,dx>\alpha\,(1-r)
%\int_r^{r+\epsilon}f+\int_{r+\epsilon}^1 f>\alpha \epsilon +\alpha (1-r-\epsilon)
$$

Comment: I believe that's finally correct :=)