# Monotonic function / fixed point related to area

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $M_a$ is the set of set monotonically decreasing functions $\{f_a\}$ on [0,1]->[0,1] with area $a=\int_0^1 f_a(x)\, dx$ (where obviously $a\in[0,1]$).($f_a$ are not necessarily strictly monotonic, not necessarily continuous, e.g. could be a step function.)

What is the envelope of the functions $f_a \in M_a$? There must be a function $g_a$ that bounds the functions $f_a$, i.e. a $g_a$ such that for each $f_a$ we have $\forall x: f_a(x) \ge g_a(x)$? If so, what is it?

This might be the same as describing fixed points, or perhaps the same as this question [Inequality on monotone function integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484518/inequality-on-monotone-function-integration) - not sure.

Answer in non-technical language appreciated! THANKS!!

Comment: Could also be related to this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593295/monotonic-function-optimization-on-convex-constraint-region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be monotonically decreasing on $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ and assume the point $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the graph of $f$. Then the minimum possible area for $f$ is $x_0y_0$ (achieved when $f(x)$ is constant at $y_0$ up to point $x=x_0$, and constant at zero after $x=x_0$), and the maximum possible area for $f$ is $1-(1-x_0)(1-y_0)$ (achieved when $f(x)$ is constant at $1$ up to point $x=x_0$ and constant at $y_0$ after $x=x_0$). In other words,
$$
x_0y_0\le \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\le 1-(1-x_0)(1-y_0).\tag{*}$$ 
So if $\int f_a = a$, then ($*$) demands that
$$xf_a(x)\le a\quad \mbox{and}\quad
1-(1-x)(1-f_a(x))\ge a$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$. [Reason: set $(x_0,y_0):=(x,f_a(x))$.]  Rearranging, this is the same as saying
$$\frac{a-x}{1-x}\le f_a(x)\le \frac ax$$
for every $x\in[0,1]$. With the additional constraint that $0\le f_a(x)\le 1$ always, this gives the upper envelope for $M_a$ as:
$$
G_a(x):=\begin{cases}
1&x<a\\
\frac ax&x\ge a
\end{cases}
$$
and the lower envelope for $M_a$ as:
$$
g_a(x):=\begin{cases}
\frac {a-x}{1-x}&x< a\\
0&x\ge a
\end{cases}.
$$
It is easy to construct examples that touch the envelopes: these are the extremal step functions defined in the first paragraph.